# syntax: match all lines with a given pattern that follow a line with a different pattern

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a Syntax file for [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html).  I want to create a color scheme for the `[Documentation]` tag, such that the text following the tag, and all subsequent lines beginning with `...` until the next line that does not begin with `...` are matched.  So for example:

```
1    Test Case 1
2        [Documentation]  This
3        ...    Is
4        ...    Documentation
5        [Setup]    Run Keywords    Keyword1
6        ...    AND        Keyword2
```

I want to match lines 2-4, but not 1, 5, or 6.  I'm not sure if this is possible, and if so, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: have a look at http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/45.html, it's a great read!

Comment: It sounds like you'll want to create a region and then create a match within that region. Pretty sure this is possible. I would also suggest the [vim wiki's page on this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files). It has a lot of good examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be possible with a `syntax region`. If you put the following in your syntax file, it should work:

```
syntax region Documentation
  \ start=/^\s*\[Documentation\]/
  \ end=/^\s*\[\|^\s*$/me=s-1
highlight link Documentation Comment
```

The highlight is only for testing to show that it works, and you probably both can and should use a different highlight. At least I think this will provide an example that you can build further upon.

For relevant help, see

- `:h :syn-region`
- `:h :syn-pattern` (for the `me=s-1` part)